# hover on picture, showing a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the same effect as this [site](http://getglue.com/movies/casino_royale/martin_campbell?source=http://getglue.com/home) (I don't think you can see it if you don't register). Here's the image that describes it [image]

As you can see when I hover on the image, it shows this box and then when I hover on youtube it automatically plays the trailer of the movie. How the hell can I do this? This just seems to be pretty amazing to me. I am guessing that they are doing this on real time

Comment: Which part do you want to know? How to do a tooltip or how to play a youtube video from javascript?

Comment: mostly interested in the tooltip, but just want to know if a tooltip can pop out when I click on that image or does it have to be on hover?

Comment: also rotten tomatoes doesn't have an API. How does it then get the score from rotten tomato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where you hover an image, that plugin is called a `ToolTip`. You can basically load up any html in it as you wish. Take a look at [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

As for playing a youtube video on hover. This is using the youtube javascript API. You can start the video right after the tooltip pops up, etc. API [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_controls).

Comment: what if instead of popping up when I hover it. it pops up when I click on the image... is this the same thing just different behavior?

Comment: Same thing, you set that event on the tooltip. You can even call it in code, on a keydown, click, etc.

Comment: also just curious how it could find the right/appropriate trailer for that movie and not some crap youtube video...

Comment: @Equinox thats up to your website admins to link the videos.

Answer (score 0):

you would want to use [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) for this.

Hey! I baked something for you [here <sup>demo</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/jEbDa/).

also a similar demo [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/youtube).